# Send an email PHP with SMTP server to Windows Server 2008

Tags: php, iis, smtp, windows-server-2008, sendmail

I would like to send an email from my PHP application. For this, I set up my website in IIS on my Windows server 2008. Can I install the Windows SMTP server.

Then I create a test page to send an email:

```
<?php
  Ini_set ('SMTP', 'localhost');
  Ini_set ('sendmail_from', 'myEmailTest@local.com');

  $to = 'myEmailTest@ExternalDomain.com';
  $subject = 'Example subject';
  $body = 'body ... With an example';

  if(mail($to, $subject, $body)){
     echo "Successful";
  }else{
     echo "Error";
  }
?>
```

I also configure php.ini and SMTP E-mail in IIS like this:

```
[Mail function]
smtp = localhost
smtp_port = 25
```

Then I test sending my mail. When I send the email to an email address of the local domain to another email address in the local domain. Me back my page "Successful" and the email goes in the folder :

```
C:\inetpub\mailroot\Drop
```

By cons, if I send an email from an email address in the local domain email address to an external domain (@ hotmail.com). Me my page returns "Error" and nothing happens.

I look at the log files of my SMTP server, but there is no error message.

Can you help me?

Comment: Well the SMTP server might not be configured to relay email for external domains. Enable `display_errors` settings and see if PHP reports some error.

Comment: How do you configure the relay?

Answer (score 1):

I successfully advanced a step. Now, when I send an email from an e-mail address of local domain to a e-mail address of an external domain (@hotmail.com), the mail is send to my PHP page, it gets stuck in against in the queue `C:\inetpub\mailroot\Queue`.

Does anyone know what is the problem?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If your page is returning with an error (most likely a 500) then you need to have a look at the PHP error logs which are separate from the SMTP error logs.  Please let us know what you find, as any error encountered while attempting to execute the php mail function, will show up in those logs.

Comment: It was I who said that if the mail () function returns false then it must echo "Error". So he just displays "Error" on my page.

I also see PHP Error Logs, but there is no error.